# Executing R statement with string

Tags: r

I have this statement:

```
y <- someVector$"2"$y
y <- someVector$"3"$y
y <- someVector$"4"$y
...
```

This works fine, but the values for 2, 3, 4 .. are a running index. So I would like to have something like the following statement in a loop:

```
y <- someVector$index$y
```

This doesn't work because I need the " around the index.

can somebody help me to make this possible?

Thanks

Comment: use `[` instead of `$`  i.e. `someVector[[index]][y]` or so, A reproducible example would be useful

Comment: Ok that was easy... Thank You